# Yeoman generator template variable as filename

Tags: variables, generator, yeoman

is it possible to set the filename while copying from a variable?

For example:
Appname is set through console.
Site Title is the appname..

```
var siteTitle = {
  site_name: this.appName
};


this.template("html/_index.html", "app/html/index.html", siteTitle);
```

This sets the Placeholder appname. Everything is fine.

But I would like to do something like: Name the css file like the appName and set the parentclass to appname(this works).

```
this.template("css/_main.css", "app/css/" + siteTitle + ".css", siteTitle);
```

Is this possible? Like this how I've already done it's not working.

Greets,
Sergej

Answer (score 2):

Ok, just fixed this problem.

Instead of using the variable

```
this.template("css/_main.css", "app/css/" + siteTitle + ".css", siteTitle);
```

I need to use the appName directly

```
this.template("css/_main.css", "app/css/" + this.appName + ".css", siteTitle);
```